# Two Devise models with different parent controllers and layouts - Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

To give you an idea of what I'm working on: I have a section inside of my main app which I've namespaced inside a "portal" route (`localhost:3000/portal`). I have two Devise models, User and Client. The Client users should only be able to access the part of the site that is namespaced under `/portal`. The other users will invite 'Clients' to the site, who will be given a link to their profile page, `localhost:3000/portal/clients/id`.

When under the portal route, I want a different layout view to be used. So I've tried making a `Portal::ApplicationController` and setting the layout (views/portal/portal_layout.html.erb) in there. This works when I'm not in a Devise view, but when I'm on a sign in or sign up view within `portal/`, Devise uses its parent controller, the main `ApplicationController`. This value is set in the Devise initializer, so I can't dynamically set it dependant upon whether or not the users is under the portal route.

Is there a solution that will make Devise use the correct `ApplicationController` as its parent controller dependant on the current path, **or is there another way that I can set a separate layout for the part of the site under** `localhost:3000/portal`**?**

Let me know if you need some more information, because I found this a bit difficult to explain. I'll leave you with my routes for now.

```
  namespace :portal do
    devise_for :clients, controllers: {
        sessions: 'portal/clients/sessions',
        registrations: 'portal/clients/registrations'
    }
    authenticate :client do
      root to: 'dashboards#index'
    end
  end
```

Comment: It would be useful to paste your routes.rb and clarify what you mean by subapp.